# Fork no Windows

Tags: c, c++, windows, posix

Existe no Windows algo como o (ou alguma alternativa similar ao) [`fork`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fork.html) dos sistemas POSIX (UNIX e Mac) para criar um processo filho que é uma exata cópia do pai e é executado a partir do ponto de chamada?

Até onde eu sei o [`CreateProcess`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425(v=vs.85).aspx) (o mais próximo *que eu conheço*) não faz nenhuma dessas duas coisas, pois cria um processo qualquer (informado via parâmetros) e executa-o desde o início (como uma nova chamada mesmo).

Comment: pelo jeito não existe não, do [SO em Inglês](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9148072/5953895).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Uma das maiores dificuldades em portar programas do Unix para o Windows está justamente no modelo de processo dos dois sistemas operacionais. O Windows não possui a chamada fork.

Dependendo de como o fork é usado no programa, ele pode ser substituído por CreateProcess, tentando contornar as diferenças das duas chamadas. Em outros casos, um aplicativo Unix que cria cópias de si mesmo pode ser modelado como um único processo com várias threads no Windows com a chamada CreateThread.

Uma maneira mais fácil seria a utilização da biblioteca Cygwin, que provê as funcionalidades da API POSIX com o DLL cygwin1.dll, incluindo a chamada fork.

Para utilizar a biblioteca basta executar os seguintes passos:

1. Entre no site https://cygwin.com/index.html e baixe o arquivo **setup-x86.exe** ou **setup-x86_64.exe** dependendo do seu sistema. Execute o instalador.
2. Clique em avançar e depois escolha install from de internet.
3. Defina o diretório para instalação do Cygwin (melhor deixa C:\cygwin64).
4. Escolha um diretório para guardar os arquivos baixados.
5. Selecione um site para download.
6. Quando chegar na opção Select Packages digite gcc e selecione gcc-core e gcc-g++. A seleção é feita clicando em cima do Skip, como mostrado na figura:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Depois de instalar o Cygwin entre na pasta em que ele foi instalado, no meu caso C:\cygwin64\home\Sergio e coloque o código que você quer compilar lá. Abra o Cygwin e compile o programa normalmente usando a chamada fork com o gcc.

Segue abaixo um código bem simples de um exemplo de utilização do fork:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
 {
    printf("Iniciando o programa\n");
    int i, j, contador = 0;
    pid_t pid = fork();

    if(pid == 0){
        for (i=0; i < 5; ++i)
             printf("Processo filho: contador=%d\n", ++contador);
    }
    else if(pid > 0){
        for (j=0; j < 5; ++j)
             printf("Processo pai: contador=%d\n", ++contador);
    }
    else{
        printf("fork() falhou!\n");
        return 1;
    }

    printf("Programa terminou\n");
    return 0;
 }
```

No meu caso compilei e executei assim:
gcc a.c -o hello
./hello

Com o Cygwin você pode inclusive misturar chamadas no Unix com chamadas do Windows, com algumas limitações. Mas lembrando, o modelo de processo dos dois sistemas operacionais é bem diferente e, portanto, as chamadas ao fork no Windows por meio do Cygwin irão ficar bem lentas!

Espero que tenha ajudado :)

Comment: Ajudou. Vc sabe se dá pra fazer a chamada de fork diretamente do código compilado no Windows (com Visual Studio, por exemplo)? Talvez fosse questão apenas de importar a DLL cygwin1.dll que vc mencionou, não? Se isso fosse possível, ficaria transparente para o usuário da aplicação a necessidade do Cygwin por baixo dos panos.

Comment: Bom, o que eu sei que dá pra ser feito é um projeto Makefile no Visual Studio que vai chamar um makefile que você mesmo fez, dai você pode compilar com o g++ do cygwin, mas não seria uma solução muito útil. Não sei se entendi direto, o que você quis dizer com código compilado? Depois de compilar o código não da mais pra usar o Cygwin! E se você usar antes de compilar ele, o cygwin1.dll vai entrar em conflito com as dlls do Visual Studio, e isso eu acho que vai ser chato de resolver.

Comment: Tem razão. O gcc no Cygwin provavelmente gera um .exe de qualquer forma, então do ponto de vista do usuário dá na mesma (ele não necessariamente precisa abrir o Cygwin antes de executar o aplicativo - era essa a minha preocupação). :)

Comment: Sim, o gcc no Cygwin vai gerar um .exe! Para que ele execute fora do Cygwin é só adicionar a cygwin1.dll que estará em C:\cygwin64\bin na mesma pasta do executável, ou no system path do Windows. E isso fica transparente para o usuário!

Answer (score 1):

Na API do Windows não tem nada que se assemelhe ao fork(). Mas a biblioteca Cygwin implementa fork() da forma mais próxima possível do padrão POSIX.

Comment: E vc teria um exemplo de uso em C++ do `fork` no/com o Cygwin?

Comment: Infelizmente não, mas o Cygwin como um todo é de código-fonte aberto, então deve ser tranquilo achar.

Comment: Não tenho dúvida de que seja tranquilo encontrar. Mas a questão é que facilitaria um bocado (não apenas a mim, mas também a outros usuários futuramente interessados no assunto) e melhoraria muito a sua resposta. Por isso que eu solicitei. Se complementar nesse sentido, ganha o meu +1. :)

Comment: A coisa mudou nos últimos dias com o tal "Ubuntu on Windows". Certamente essa camada oferece uma implementação mais fiel do fork() do que o Cygwin.